# Git restore branch with changed history

Tags: git, gitlab, git-reflog, git-history

I created a branch

```
git checkout -b myBranch
```

I made 3 commits onto the branch, lets name then `One`, `Two`and `Three`.

I did an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

With

```
pick One
drop Two
drop Three
```

and after dropping `Two` and `Three` I did a force push:

```
git push -f
```

I lost access to the local branch and just have access to `origin`.

Gitlab shows the hash ID of 'Three'. Still even I am not able to checkout the `Three` commit being child of `Two`.

After a new clone of the branch `git reflog` does not show relevant commit of `Three`. I assume because the history has changed on `origin`.

Comment: Have you looked into `git reflog`? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: Relevant git book chapter: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery skip to "Data recovery". It covers virtually this exact scenario

Comment: feel free to use the commit id that you have to put your branch there: `git reset --hard the-commit-id` (make sure to not have uncommitted stuff laying around your working tree because that will discard those changes).

Comment: Although `reset --hard` is a command to be treated with respect and should normally not be an everyday command. I would rather suggest rather starting with `git branch myBranch2 the-commit-id` and then after you have inspected the code/history (with `gitk --all &` for instance) and are really sure `myBranch2` is what you want, then you can run `git checkout myBranch; git reset --hard myBranch2` to reset `myBranch` to be `myBranch2`.